# How to install a python module in ONLY virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am able to install python module in virtualenv but it is accessible outside the virtualenv as well. How to restrict its usage in virtualenv?

I went to the virtualenv path and then typed activate. It got activated as I could see root at the beginning.

And then I used the command pip install module_name

Activated the virutal env and then deactivated it.

When I activated the virtual env I was able to import the module.
When I deactivated it still the module was easily imported.

I assume the module was installed globally. I want it to be installed only in virtual env and should not be accessible outside.

[image: ACTIVATED THE VIRTUAL ENV AND Td MODULE WAS IMPORTABLE AND THEN DEACTIVATED IT BUT STILL MODULE WAS STILL IMPORTABLE]

Comment: Installing a module in a virtualenv shouldn't make it accessible from outside the venv. What did you do to create the virtualenv, activate it, and install the modules (please edit the question)

Comment: When virtualenv activated you can see env name at the beginning.
first, activate virtualenv then install python modules using pip.
please share a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 name_of_venv #to create venv
source name_of_venv/bin/activate #to activate venv
pip install module_name #to install module`

Answer (score 0):

The virtualenv tool is basically used to isolate the dependencies required for multiple projects. The python version installed within virtualenv won't be visible in the global directory.Try following the below steps properly in the virtualenv.

```
pip install virtualenv

cd my_project_folder

virtualenv venv

virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7

source venv/bin/activate

[Vitualenv Link:][1]
```

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

It is not visible from the outside. As soon as you type `deactivate` it is no longer importable.

Comment: I typed deactivate but it is still importable.

Comment: The screenshot isn't quite relevant. Make a screenshot where it is clear that you try to import a module and it doesn't work, then you create venv, activate it, install module, deactivate vent and it import still works.